# Matrix inverse - measure of approximation

Tags: matrices, approximation, inverse

I have a matrix, if I apply inverse function from existing softwares, I get an inverse matrix for every non singular matrix.

I would like to know if there is a measure that tells that how close the approximation to check weather to consider the inverse matrix not.

In my application, there is a possibility to discard an inverse matrix that's not well approximated.

I am looking for few hints, keywords to look for or an advice in calculating the measure.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: How about $\| BA - I  \|$?

Comment: Hi, is B = A inverse? and check A inverse time A should equal to I? how can i calculate a single value for the measure? The lower the sum of all elements the better?

Comment: Try various matrix norms